# Appearing and dissapearing particle trails in skript minecraft? (.sk)

Tags: minecraft

I want to make it so when I right click an item I get particle trail for set amount of ticks

For more explanation:

I am making a leap ability where by right clicking an item you get pushed up and forwards, I have done the leap and now I want to add a trail that spawns in for a few seconds after you have right clicked the item.

Here is my code so far:

`on right click:

if player's held item is totem of undying named "&e&lLeap":
send "You have used &a&lLeap" to player
play sound "entity.bat.takeoff" at volume 100 to player
push player up at speed 0.3
push player forward at speed 1
set player's max health to 8`

This works I just have no idea on how to create a trail that follows the players feet for a brief moment.